# Opt-in / Opt-out Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to create a simple way to force a single checkbox to display "No" in a form submission if left unchecked, or clicked off. I've tried a number of ways and this is the closest I can get, but it still isn't working properly.

Any help is much appreciated.
Matt

```
$(function opt() {
        if ($("#optIn").is(":checked")) {
            $("#optIn").value="Yes"
            $("#optIn").click(function() { this.value="No" })
        } else {
            $("#optIn").value="No"
            $("#optIn").click(function() { this.value="Yes" })
        }
    return false
});

opt();
```

Comment: 1. JQuery object don't have the `.value` property as far as I remember. You should use `.val("newvalue")` when you want to change the value. 2. Changing the value won't print anything in the screen, it's just the checkbox's value which will be sent when you submit the form. You'd have to create a `<span>` with the label for it which you'd like to edit with `.html("newlabel")` if you want to display something in the form, which is what you want apparently.

Comment: I think both of your click() handlers will get placed on the control and both will get executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to start out quite frankly, I'm not sure where you saw that sort of function setup before. You're code, as-is, could be reduced to this:

```
$(function() { // on DOM ready (when the DOM is finished loading)
    $('#optIn').click(function() { // when the checkbox is clicked
        var checked = $('#optIn').is(':checked'); // check the state
        $('#optIn').val(checked ? "Yes" : "No"); // set the value
    });
    $('#optIn').triggerHandler("click"); // initialize the value
});
```

The `value` of the checkbox, however, is never displayed on the screen. You may need to update a separate field with the values "Yes" or "No", such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optIn" />
<span id="optInLabel"/>No</span>
```

And the script:

```
$(function() { // on DOM ready (when the DOM is finished loading)
    $('#optIn').click(function() {
        optIn(this);
    });
    optIn($('#optIn')[0]);
});

function optIn(el) {
    var checked = $(el).is(':checked'); // check the state
    $('#optInLabel').html(checked ? "Yes" : "No"); // set the value
}
```

**EDIT: [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9mqm/)**

If you need to check whether the box is checked on the server-side post-form-submission, then you could also update a hidden input field with the value "Yes" or "No" and ignore the submitted checkbox element value (as `jaredhoyt` mentioned in his answer).

Comment: Just setting the value of the checkbox will not be enough as an unchecked checkbox will not be submitted with the POSTed data. You would also have to add a form submission event handler to manually check the box before submit.

Comment: Quick writing skills, +1 for the span label now.

Answer (score 7):

An unchecked checked box is not a [successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) and is therefore not POSTed with the rest of the form data.

The easiest solution for this is to create a hidden input with the same name as your checkbox that will contain the "unchecked" value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myCheckbox" value="No" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="Yes" />
```

This will cause the form to POST `myCheckbox=No` if the checkbox is left unchecked.

Comment: Does the checkbox value override the hidden value if it's checked? Does order of the HTML matter for that? I noticed the name attr is the same. Thanks!

Comment: Am I wrong or this isn't quite necessary..? Say, assuming OP has only 1 `myCheckbox` which can either be checked or not, if it's not checked when the form is submitted, the OP may perfectly well test `if (!$_POST['myCheckbox'])` in the php and assume it was left unchecked, assigning a "No" value to it in the php itself. The question isn't relative to PHP and I don't know about other server-side languages, but just leaving it here for thought.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Java behaves the same way as the param would be null. In fact, I bet a lot of languages handle it the same way due to the [Robustness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) and HTTP being a standard...

Comment: @jmort253 - Yes, the second value will override the hidden input and order of the inputs does matter.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Yes, in many cases you can just test for a null value on server-side. I assumed OP had a reason for needing a "Yes" or "No" string to be POSTed and answered the question accordingly (and without JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks Jared. While I think @FabrícioMatté has a good point, I can see the value in explicitly passing "No" as it could make the code more readable for server-side devs. +1 for creativity.

Comment: Yes, I only asked because I wasn't sure if there was a special reason for that. Also I'm still a little bit confused as how one value overwrites another.. Say, if they were 2 checkboxes with the same name, and both were checked, both values would be passed as an array right? Or do I actually need to add [] to the name as in `myCheckbox[]` for the server to interpret it as an array? Or is it because the input types are different? I'm guessing the lack of `[]` in the name is what does the overriding, just wondering.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question above, but it just got me curious .-. reply that and I'll +1 w/o questions. :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté If a form has two controls of the same name, the last successful control in the form will be submitted. To post multiple values for the same name, the you would need to add the `[]` suffix.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming it @jaredhoyt, it just reminded me of the issues I had with that before. +1 to you.

Comment: If two or more (successful) form controls have the same name _all_ are definitely submitted even without the `[]` suffix. Adding `[]` to have multiple values with the same parameter name is a PHP thing that does not apply to all server-side technologies (and that makes no difference at all to the browser).

Comment: @nnnnnn You are correct. I assumed that only the last control would be POSTed since only the last value is usually retained server-side (unless `[]` is used such as in PHP or C#). Thanks for the correction. +1

Comment: I think in Java it's the other way around: if you use `.getParameter()` it returns the _first_ value (or null if the parameter didn't exist). If you use `.getParameterValues()` it returns an array (of length 1 if there was only one, or null if the parameter didn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons:

```
<span>Opt in?</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="optIn" value="no" checked>No&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="optIn" value="yes">Yes
```

No javascript required, works in every browser, no shims, no libraries, nothing.